# Java: How to order by entity.fieldA

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by

I have a problem when querying a database and ordering the resultSet base on entity.fieldA.

For example, in the school context (student, teacher). I have teacher with many students.

```
//Student class
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID")
private Teacher teacher;
```

And I want my query to be sorted by teacher.name, but only teacher is available from me.

So having the query:

```
FROM Student s ORDER BY s.teacher;
```

It did not work even if I implement comparable on teacher:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Teacher o) {
  return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
}
```

My query:

```
from Student a left join fetch a.teacher where a.xid=:xxx ORDER BY a.teacher ASC
```

I have a framework that's why I'm not able to sort by a.teacher.name, so I'm asking if even with a.teacher and implementing Comparable interface, sorting by a.teacher.name can be achieve.

This problem comes from a lazy loaded dataTable, when you click an entity column to sort it will only give you the entity name not the field.

Any idea?

Comment: you have to join Teacher t with Students s and then order by t.name

Comment: Sorry I think I'm not clear, I've added more info in my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL queries are translated to SQL queries and executed by your database. And your database doesn't know and care about your classes and their `compareTo()` method.

You just need

```
select s from Student s order by s.teacher.name
```

Read [the documentation about HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins) to understand how joins work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this problem by having a dynamic column and runtime adding of sortBy property:

```
<c:if test="#{sort}">
    <c:if test="#{empty childField}">
        <f:attribute name="sortBy" value="#{field}" />
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{not empty childField}">
        <f:attribute name="sortBy" value="#{field}.#{childField}" />
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

So what the code does is sort by field if childField is not set. Otherwise if it's an entity like teacher it sets that entity's property as the sort field, in our case teacher.name.